# How can I consume a JSON web service with Restlet?

Tags: java, json, rest, restlet, restlet-2.0

I'm trying to consume a restful web service with Restlet.  The service is giving me JSON, so I'm using a JsonRepresentation object to get it, but it's not working.  I'm getting a null pointer exception when I call `jsonRepresentation.getJsonObject()`.

Here is my code:

```
ClientResource resource = 
    new ClientResource("https://api.prosper.com/api/Listings?$top=3");
resource.setChallengeResponse(
    ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, 
    "username", 
    "password");
try {
    JsonRepresentation jsonRepresentation = 
        new JsonRepresentation(resource.getResponse().getEntity());
    jsonRepresentation.getJsonObject();
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

Any idea what the issue could be or how I could trouble shoot this?

Comment: debug the contents of resource.getResponse().  I'm guessing the authentication is wrong or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you missed the call to the service:

```
ClientResource resource = (...)
(...)
Representation repr = resource.get();
JsonRepresentation jsonRepresentation = new JsonRepresentation(repr);
JSONObject jsonObj = jsonRepresentation.getJsonObject();
```

Hope it helps you.
Thierry